# ffmpeg avcodec_encode_video2 to avcodec_decode_video2

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am completely confused as to why this is not working...

So I have verified that my mjpg encode is working as I have verified that the jpg image after I wrote it to file.  As a test I wanted to decode the data after I encoded it, just for a sanity check, but I keep getting an access violation, and I am completely lost as to why.

This is how I defined my decode buffer

```
AVFrame *pFrameDecoded = avcodec_alloc_frame();
int num_bytes2 = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P, 320, 248);
uint8_t* frame2_buffer2 = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(num_bytes2*sizeof(uint8_t));
avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)pFrameDecoded, frame2_buffer2, PIX_FMT_YUVJ422P, 320, 240);
```

This is the code segment that is failing...

```
AVPacket packet 
av_init_packet(&packet);            
packet.data = NULL;
packet.size = 0;


out_size = avcodec_encode_video2(codecContext, &packet, frame2, &got_output);
if (got_output && got_output > 0) {
  int finaldone;
  // ERROR OCCURS HERE!!!
  avcodec_decode_video2( codecContext, pFrameDecoded, &finaldone, &packet ); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So your crash  happens because you initialized codecContext for encoding, and its current state (such as last frame kept) is related to encoding. But now you attempt to use the same context for decoding. Codec context is attached to a specific video file and operation. For example, you cannot have one context, pass to it random packets from different videos and expect it working. You'd need to initialize a different context in your case for decoding.

Also you need to check for the `out_size` value to be non-negative as in your case it is possible that `got_output` is 1 but the `avcodec_encode_video2` still returned an error.

Answer (score 0):

In statement `IF(got_output && got_output > 0)` the logical condition is always `true`. So the inner statements block is always processed even when `got_output==0`. This could be the reason of crash.